# HTML form snippet for contribution page

Tags: civicontribute, profile

When using CiviCRM with drupal, is there a way of using a HTML form snippet with a contribution page, as is possible with a normal profile? If so could someone direct me as to how to do this?

Thanks!
Andrew

Answer (score 2):

[CiviCRM inlay](https://civicrm.org/extensions/inlay) gives html snippet that you can embed on any website. It has minimum settings for now.